# How to include all necessary files and folders in python executable file using pyinstaller on ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cakephp-3.x

I want to keep all the python script files hidden and want to give executable file to the user.
Here's the screeenshot of the folder:
[image: Here's the screeenshot of the folder]

I am running it from the webroot directory of a project.I am going to run my project on the local host. In the Al3ViewerController I have given path to the main.py/ exe main file using shell_exec. But I need to keep the folder containing all the other python and DB files and I cannot do that for code security purpose, hence an exe file to run. could be --onefile / folder. I would want to remove that folder completely and just run from the executable file

Comment: What does this have to do with CakePHP?

Comment: I am going to run my project on the local host. In the Al3ViewerController I have given path to the main.py/ exe main file using shell_exec. But I need to keep the folder containing all the other python and DB files but I cannot give this to the user, hence an exe file to run. could be --onefile / folder.